# Copied redis dump.rdb server to new server, only loads < 5 MB into memory instead of ~1 GB from previous server

Tags: ubuntu, cache, redis

I am migrating redis servers (from 2.2 to 2.6, if that's relevant), and after I do a "SAVE" on the old box and copy the file to the new box, I put it in the same location from /etc/redis/redis.conf as "dir" and with the same "dbfilename".

Excerpts from /etc/redis/redis.conf

```
dbfilename dump.rdb
dir /data/redis
appendonly no
appendfsync everysec
```

1st step, shutdown redis.

2nd step: copy the file to the correct dest

```
# ls -lh /data/redis/dump.rdb
-rw-rw---- 1 redis redis 343M Aug 30 04:10 /data/redis/dump.rdb
```

3rd step: Launch redis

```
/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

4th step: Check INFO from redis-cli

```
# redis-cli INFO | grep used_memory_human
used_memory_human:4.78M
```

The same command on the server I'm migrating *from* reports `used_memory_human:999.13M`.  I expect these to be the same.

Just to further confirm that the data was never loaded, if I SAVE or shutdown the new redis server, the dump.rdb file is 1.8 MB.

What am I doing wrong? Multiple articles I've read say this is a perfectly fine way to migrate redis to a new server